# Xcode project migration

Tags: xcode, linker-errors, xcode-project

I'm trying to copy a XCode project from one Mac to another. Simply, I zipped the project directory, copy to the another machine and opened the project with Xcode.

The project doesn't build perfect, it generates the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So, i have these questions:

1- Is it possible to copy the directory project and generate on another Mac?

2- Can I generate an executable with another account Apple developer on the new machine?

3- How to resolve the library not found error? The library really is there.

Comment: "The library really is there" It's inside the project directory somewhere, and it was copied over?

Comment: it was there (inside the project directory) in red color.